# Command Line Argument

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am having trouble figuring out how to make this code work. What is suppose to is depending on the arguments giving from the command line, it suppose to print out a greeting.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

double testscore;

    if (argc == 2) {
        printf("Hello, Mr.%s.\n", argv[1]);

    }
    else if (argc == 3 && argc == testscore) {
        testscore = atof(argv[2]);
        printf("Hi, Mr.%s, your score is %.1f\n", argv[1], testscore);
    }
    else  {

        printf("My name is %s %s.\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    }
}
```

If someone puts only their last name, then the terminal will print out...

> Hello, Mr. last_name

...because they only put in one argument. This works fine.

The part where I am stuck on is when the command line arguments given are `== 3`. If 3 arguments are given then either the terminal is suppose to print out...

> Hi, Mr. last_name, your test score is test_score

...or...

> My name is first_name last_name.

If I put in the command line arguments only the last name and test score (Smith 3.4) then it prints out (example using the last name Smith) then it prints out...

> My name is Smith 3.4

However, it does work for putting in the first name and last name (John Smith). This gives...

> My name is John Smith.

**I do not want the answer**, I just want what I am doing wrong and hints on how to fix it.

Comment: "Starting Out with C++" by Tony Gaddis, right? Either way, thank you for not asking for code outright. It's rare among newbies.

Comment: This is a simple typo. You're testing `argc == testscore`, which is testing **the number of arguments** against the score. Thus, the second conditional will never evaluate to true (except by some weird fluke).

Comment: `testscore` is uninitialized, so you can't usefully compare it before you set it.  You should probably try to convert `argv[2]` with `atof()` (`strtod()` would be better — but harder to get right) and compare the result with 0.0.  It is a bit lazy but probably reasonable to assume that if the result is zero, `argv[2]` doesn't contain a number, so treat it as a name.  (A more thorough job would use `strtod()` and check whether a number such as 0 was found.)  You might like to think what happens if the program is passed no command line arguments, or if it is passed 20 of them.  Should you check?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it has since occured to me that there is the distinct possibility this just *looks similar* to one of Gaddis' assignments. I think his version involved `cout`. All the same, it's homework.

Comment: @JasonMc92: I've edited my comment to remove that bit.  Agreed this is probably homework — but as you said, the question is well presented (once the code is formatted).

Comment: @JasonMc92 It is a homework assignment but as of lately I really want to learn how to program so lately I have trying to practice more. So, I really do not want to just ask for the answer. I want to actually understand. I will test it  with the comments later. Thank you.

Comment: @SoonPro I know, and you have no idea how refreshing that attitude is. :) There have been at least 500 questions today alone of newbies asking for us to "give me da codez!!!!"  All the best to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
else if (argc == 3 && argc == testscore) {
```

In fact, when argc == 3, then you want to check if argv[2] is a numeric argument.

```
else if ( (argc==3) && (is_numeric_arg(argv[2])==1)) {
```

A possible implementation would be:

```
int is_numeric_arg(char* arg)
    {
        int isInt = 0;
        int isFloat = 0;
        int isChar = 0;
        char* currChar;
        int i = 0;
        currChar = arg;
        isInt = 1;
        while (*currChar != '\0')
        {
            if(*currChar < '0' || *currChar > '9')
            {
                if(*currChar == '.' && isInt == 1)
                {
                    isInt = 0;
                    isFloat = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    isInt = 0;
                    isChar = 1;
                }
            }
            currChar++;
        }
        if (isChar == 1){ return 0; } // argument is a string
        else { return 1; } // argument is a int or float
    }

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    double testscore;

    if (argc == 2) {
        printf("Hello, Mr.%s.\n", argv[1]);

    }
    else if ( (argc==3) && (is_numeric_arg(argv[2])==1)) {
        testscore = atof(argv[2]);
        printf("Hi, Mr.%s, your score is %.1f\n", argv[1], testscore);
    }
    else  {

        printf("My name is %s %s.\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
    }
}
```

I did not test the code and there is probably a better way to check that the argument from the command line is "numeric".

Comment: Thanks. I understood it. I will mess around with it and see how to better check the argument from the command line is "numeric".

Comment: Actually, one question, why in the if statement if                                     (*currChar == '.' && isInt == 1)
                {
                    isInt = 0;
                    isFloat = 1;
                }    is isInt set to 0 in this and in the else statement but before it was equal to 1? Thanks again.

Comment: the idea was to stop checking for a numeric value as soon as we see a character. Basically, the line "if(*currChar == '.' && isInt == 1)" is always false as soon as we get a char. As I said, this is a quick and dirty implementation of "is_numeric". You could also have used sscanf or other C++ library function to check for numeric value.

Answer (score 3):

> I do not want the answer, I just want what I am doing wrong and hints on how to fix it.

Problem 1: You are using `testscore` variable before it is being initialized.

Problem 2: You are not performing error handling with `atof`. I would suggest to use `strtod()`. You can perform some error handling with it to know that the third argument is a float or not. You can also create your own implementation of `atof()` which will convert and report error in conversion, if any.

Hint: Try to first check that the number of arguments passed to the c program. After that, try to convert third argument to float using `strtod()` or your own implementation. If it successfully converts, assign the result of float convrsion to `test_score` and print `last_name` and `testscore`. If not, then consider third argument as `last_name` and print `first_name` and `last_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it the answer guys. To check it without using another function, it would be

....

```
else if ( argc==3 && sscanf(argv[2], "%f", testscore) 


{


    testscore = atof(argv[2]);

    printf("Hi, Mr.%s, your score is %.1f\n", argv[1], testscore);
}
```

...